# Error id accion

Tags: mysql, mvc, jsp, servlets

Este es mi problema.

Tengo un proyecto trabajándolo bajo el modelo `MVC` (Modelo, vista, controlador) y `jsp` con conexión a una base de datos `sql` y sus correspondiente código por `java`.

Tengo un formulario que muestra las personas y había logrado que un botón me llevara a un formulario para actualizar el usuario seleccionado, escribirle un estado de habilitado o deshabilitado en la base de datos (Básicamente un `update`) y eliminarlo.

Todo esto me funcionaba correctamente pero ahora tengo un problema, que es que solo me funciona el `update` y el eliminar con el ultimo `id` de los usuarios.

Por ejemplo tengo tres usuarios, con `id` 3,4,5 correspondientemente, pero al habilitar, deshabilitar o eliminar sin importar cual elija, siempre hará la respectiva acción con el ultimo `id` y no con el deseado.

Lo extraño es que esto me funcionaba perfectamente, en la escuela después de unas horas ocurrió este error y en casa a pesar de que trabajar con un proyecto y base de datos mas viejo pero que aun así funcionaban, ya no sirven.

La única forma de hacerlo funcionar bien es cuando en la barra de la dirección web escrita pongo el controlador con el id que quiero, ejemplo:

```
http://localhost:50091/student_follow_upultimo/Controlador?accion=Deshabilitar&idPersona=21
```

Adjunto segmentos de código correspondientes, espero haberme hecho explicar y disculpen la longitud del post.

**Pagina:**

```
<th>Número de Identidad</th>
                                                <th>Nombres</th>
                                                <th>Apellidos</th>
                                                <th>Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
                                                <th>Edad</th>
                                                <th>Dirección</th>
                                                <th>Teléfono</th>
                                                <th>Correo Electrónico</th>
                                                <th>Nombre de Usuario</th>

                                                <th>Numero de Rol</th>
                                                <th>Numero de Tipo de Documento</th>
                                                <th>Estado</th>
                                                <th>Actualizar Usuario</th>
                                                <th>Habilitar Usuario</th>
                                                <th>Deshabilitar Usuario</th>
                                                <th>Eliminar Usuario</th>
                                                <tr class="spacer"></tr>

                                            </tr>

                                        </thead>
                                        <%
                                        PersonaDAO dao=new PersonaDAO();
                                        List<Persona>list=dao.listar();
                                        Iterator<Persona>iter=list.iterator();
                                        Persona per=null;
                                        while(iter.hasNext()){
                                        per=iter.next();

                                        %>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr class="tr-shadow">

                                                <td><center><%= per.getdni()%></center></td>
                                                <td><center><%= per.getnombres()%></center></td>
                                                <td><center><%= per.getapellidos()%></center></td>
                                                <td><center><%= per.getfechaNacimiento()%></center></td>
                                                <td><center><%= per.getedad()%></center></td>
                                                <td><center><%= per.getdireccion()%></center></td>
                                                <td><center><%= per.gettelefono()%></center></td>
                                                <td><center><%= per.getcorreoElectronico()%></center></td>
                                                <td><center><%= per.getnombreUsuario()%></center></td>

                                                <td><center><%= per.getrol_idRol()%></center></td>
                                                <td><center><%= per.gettipodoc_idTipoDoc()%></center></td>
                                                <td><center><%= per.getestado()%></center></td>
                                                <td><center><a href="Controlador?accion=Editar&idPersona=<%= per.getidPersona()%>"><button href="Controlador?accion=Editar&idPersona=<%= per.getidPersona()%>" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Actualizar los datos de un usuario"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button></center></td>
                                                <td><center><button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Habilitar a un usuario su ingreso" onClick="mensaje2()"><i class="far fa fa-key"></i></button></center></td>
                                                <td><center><button class="btn btn-secondary" onClick="mensaje1()" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Deshabilitar a un usuario su ingreso"><i class="far fa fa-lock"></i></button></center></td>
                                                <td><center><button class="btn btn-danger" onClick="mensaje()" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar un usuario"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button></center></td>
                                                <tr class="spacer"></tr>

        <script>
            function mensaje() {
            Swal.fire({
  title: '¿Estas seguro de eliminar este usuario?',
  text: "¡Esta accion no se puede deshacer!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Si, deseo eliminar este usuario.'

}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    location.href="Controlador?accion=Eliminar&idPersona=<%= per.getidPersona()%>";
  }
})
            }
            function mensaje1() {
            Swal.fire({
  title: '¿Estas seguro de deshabiliar este usuario?',
  text: "¡El usuario no podra ingresar!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Si, deseo deshabilitar este usuario.'

}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    location.href="Controlador?accion=Deshabilitar&idPersona=<%= per.getidPersona()%>";
  }
})
            }
            function mensaje2() {
            Swal.fire({
  title: '¿Estas seguro de habilitar este usuario?',
  text: "¡El usuario podra ingresar!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Si, deseo habilitar este usuario.'

}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    location.href="Controlador?accion=Habilitar&idPersona=<%= per.getidPersona()%>";
  }
})
            }
            </script>
```

**Controlador/Servlet**:

```
else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("Eliminar")){
            idPersona=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idPersona"));
            p.setidPersona(idPersona);
            dao.delete(idPersona);
            acceso=dele;
        }
        else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("Deshabilitar")){
            idPersona=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idPersona"));
            p.setidPersona(idPersona);
            dao.deshabilitar(p);
            acceso=des;
        }
        else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("Habilitar")){
            idPersona=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idPersona"));
            p.setidPersona(idPersona);
            dao.habilitar(p);
            acceso=hab;
        }
```

**DAO:**

```
@Override
    public boolean delete(int idPersona) {
        String sql="delete from persona where idPersona="+idPersona;
        try {
            con=cn.getConnection();
            ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean habilitar(Persona per) {
        String sql="update persona set estado='Habilitado'where idPersona="+per.getidPersona();
        try {
            con=cn.getConnection();
            ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean deshabilitar(Persona per) {
        String sql="update persona set estado='Deshabilitado'where idPersona="+per.getidPersona();
        try {
            con=cn.getConnection();
            ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return false;
    }
```

````
```[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PUr4.png
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soy nuevo en ***Stackoverflow*** así que no se si es la manera correcta de responderte. Pero lo que pasa es que primero recorres tu `array` de personas armas tu tabla pero siempre queda la última persona del `array` en el objeto per. Entonces cuando llamas a tu `function` le estas diciendo que ***<% per(en este caso la ultima persona) %>***, cuando lo correcto sería que guardes solo el `id`.

Espero que se entienda. Saludos

```js
function mensaje2(id) {
    window.location.href = "Controlador?accion=Habilitar&idPersona="+id;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Habilitar a un usuario su ingreso" onClick="mensaje2(<% out.print("+per.getidPersona()+") %>)"></button>
```